# Granting bulk access to Google Cloud project for multiple users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on a workshop to be delivered in one day. The workshop will require the 50-or-so attendees to have access to a few resources in a Google  Cloud project.

What is a nice way to grant access in bulk to 50 user accounts easily? Options that I see are:

- Collect their emails, and add permissions for each in the cloud project.

  - I've done this before, but it's troublesome and it won't scale.
- Provide them with a service account key that they can download, and use.

  - This seems the least troublesome one; but it may be insecure, and aren't service accounts mostly meant for non-human users?

Is there any other way to accomplish this efficiently? Maybe programatically?

Comment: The answer that John Mahowald is correct. However, a very easy way is to just use gcloud and for loop over a list of email addresses adding each one. Another very easy method is a simple Python program to add users to the project. More information about what the users need to do would help with the best answer. For example, log in to the Google Cloud Console, run the CLI, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcloud auth to service accounts is allowed. User accounts are the default for interactive use because people tend to know their Google creds.

Multiple service accounts are allowed. Create 50 of these with suitable IAM roles. Distribute unique keys to everyone for use in  [`gcloud auth activate-service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorizing_with_a_service_account).

I think the console requires a Google user account.

You as project owner can revoke any of this at any time.